# In Elasticsearch, how do you find out if an index's fields have doc_values set to true?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I run the following to get the mapping, it doesn't tell me which fields have doc_values set to true (or which fields have index set to true, for that matter).  Is there a command or query to get that information?

```
GET sample/_mapping
```

Response:

```
    {
      "sample" : {
        "mappings" : {
          "dynamic" : "strict",
          "properties" : {
            "division" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "losses" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "members" : {
              "type" : "nested",
              "properties" : {
                "age" : {
                  "type" : "integer"
                },
                "code" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "exp" : {
                  "type" : "float"
                },
                "height" : {
                  "type" : "integer"
                },
                "memberId" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "weight" : {
                  "type" : "integer"
                }
              }
            },
            "teamAge" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "teamId" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "wins" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Both `doc_values` and `index` are true by default, if you didn't explicitly disable them in the map, then they are enabled for the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

They are not shown because they ave the default value.
By default `doc_value` and `index` are `true`

## To test

```json
PUT 72493929-3
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "status_code": { 
        "type":  "long",
        "index": true,
        "doc_values": true
      },
      "session_id": { 
        "type":  "long",
        "index": false,
        "doc_values": false
      }
    }
  }
}

GET 72493929-3/_mapping
```

Which will give you :

```json
{
  "72493929" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "session_id" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "index" : false,
          "doc_values" : false
        },
        "status_code" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```